# Python Package and Methods not Importing

Tags: python, class, packaging

I built a simple class with a couple methods to make my life a little easier when loading data into Postgres with Python. I also attempted to package it so I could pip install it (just to experiment, never done that before).

```
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import io


class py_psql:

    engine = None

    def engine(self, username, password, hostname, port, database):
        connection = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(ntid.lower(), pw, hostname, port, database)
        self.engine = create_engine(connection)


    def query(self, query):
        pg_eng = self.engine
        return pd.read_sql_query(query, pg_eng)


    def write(self, write_name, df, if_exists='replace', index=False):
        mem_size = df.memory_usage().sum()/1024**2
        pg_eng = self.engine

        def write_data():
            df.head(0).to_sql(write_name, pg_eng, if_exists=if_exists,index=index)
            conn = pg_eng.raw_connection()
            cur = conn.cursor()
            output = io.StringIO()
            df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
            output.seek(0)
            contents = output.getvalue()
            cur.copy_from(output, write_name, null="")
            conn.commit()

        if mem_size > 100:
            validate_size = input('DataFrame is {}mb, proceed anyway? (y/n): '.format(mem_size))
            if validate_size == 'y':        
                write_data()
            else:
                print("Canceling write to database")
        else:
            write_data()
```

My package directory looks like this:

```
py_psql
    py_psql.py
    __init__.py
setup.py
```

My **init**.py is empty since I read elsewhere that I was able to do that. I'm not remotely an expert here...

I was able to pip install that package and import it, and if I were to paste this class into a python shell, I would be able to do something like

```
test = py_psql()
test.engine(ntid, pw, hostname, port, database)
```

and have it create the sqlalchemy engine. However, when I import it after the pip install I can't even initialize a py_psql object:

```
>>> test = py_psql()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

>>> py_psql.engine(ntid, pw, hostname, port, database)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'py_psql' has no attribute 'engine'
```

I'm sure I'm messing up something obvious here, but I found the process of packaging fairly confusing while researching this. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: how do you import it?

Comment: try adding `from py_psql import py_psql` into your `__init__.py` file and then try `test = py_psql.py_psql()`.  Having so many things all called "`py_psql`" is making it needlessly confusing.

Comment: also, why are there two `py_psql` files/directories in your package directory? Is one mispelled here or is in an accidental duplicate line?

Comment: @Ruzihm that didn't work. And I was pretty confused by the entire directory structure, so that was what I thought I was supposed to do. I'm very open to understanding the right way to do this.

Comment: @MCO "import py_psql"

Comment: Please be more descriptive than "that didn't work"

Comment: @Ruzihm adding `from py_psql import py_psql` into init and then trying `import py_psql; test = py_psql.py_psql()` didn't work. I was able to get things to work when I imported it like `from py_psql import py_psql; test = py_psql.py_psql()`, I just realized. I apologize for not making this easier to understand. I'm also not sure why I have to import it this way, so an explanation would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you imported your package correctly after pip install?

For example:

```
from py_psql.py_psql import py_psql
test = py_psql()
test.engine(ntid, pw, hostname, port, database)
```

Comment: That worked! If you (anyone) could explain how I can clean up my directory to avoid all the "py_psql" nonsense that would be wonderful.

Comment: I would rename your `py_psql` class to something else such as `sql_manager`, rename `py_psql.py` to something like `main.py`, add `from main import sql_manager` to your `__init__.py` file, and then when you want to import it, you can do: `from py_psql import sql_manager ; test = sql_manager()`

Comment: @Ruzihm oh I get it, thank you! that makes more sense... this is perfect for me, but if I wanted to **just** say `import py_pysql` or `import sql_manager` without a `from`, how would I set everything up to do that (if possible)?

Comment: You could do `import py_pysql ; test = py_pysql.sql_manager()`. It's a rule of python that modules (such as `py_pysql`) can't be callable, and you either need to use `from`, `module.xyz`, or an equivalent to get to something that is in the module such as the `sql_manager` class you want.

Comment: @Ruzihm I made the changes like you suggested (changing to main.py, etc) and when I try to do `from py_psql import sql_manager` i get an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'`. Do I need to alter the setup.py file to reference main.py at all?

Comment: @kemri np! Please accept my answer if you feel that I have answered your question.